# Python multiprocessing pool jams after all the process is done

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, cpu

I have around 10k rows that needs to be processed and stored inside the database. and to do that I am using python3 with cx_Oracle lib and python multiprocessing capabilities, the problem is that when I am running the script it will run fine the first time, but the second time it will stuck after all the process has finished, but it wont continue running the code after the part it is done with the itereation.

```
print("MAIN PROCESS")
with multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool() as pool:
     func = partial(get_ticket_process, tixs)
     pool.map(func, [(idx,row) for idx,row in dataMain.iterrows()])
     pool.close()
     pool.terminate()
     pool.join()
```

Above it the part of code where I initialize the multiprocessing and im using partial because i need to pass some arguments to get_ticket_process function. I hope anyone have idea why is this happening.

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of using a context manager (with `with`) is that some operations will be done for you, including closing the `Pool. Try without the last 3 lines.

Comment: @Trevis at the end of the `with` block, `terminate` would be called automatically, which would also be called when the `Pool` instance was garbage collected. But I really don't think this is causing the OP's problem.

Comment: This is far from a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And it's not very clear from your description where it is you are getting stuck? Is it executing the `map` call or afterwards? And when you say it jams the second time running the script, you are actually starting up the script a second time from the command line? And what iteration are you talking about?

Comment: @Trevis I will try to remove those 3 lines and see if it solves the issue.
Booboo I think it is stuck after the pool.map call, because I can see all the rows are processed and inserted into the database but the script hangs afterwards, and the iteration im talking about is the mainData.iterrows part inside the pool map.

Comment: Is there a lock on some data in the table?  Are you using session pooling in an older version of cx_Oracle and forgetting to use `threaded=True` when you create the pool?  Do you really need 'multiprocessing' or should/could you load data with [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)?